# Unit test loop has run for particular number of times

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

Lets say I have a method looking like this

```
static void forLoop(){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

If I am to write a unit test to check the for loop was run 10 times. Is it possible to do this?

I was asked this question in an interview.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`System.setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) to redirect output to a different `PrintStream` (such as [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)), call the method and then examine the contents of the `PrintStream`.

By then, as @Andy Turner points out in the comments, you'll need to make sure that your tests don't run in parallel with each other or with anything else that might be writing to `System.out`.

(I think it's a *terrible* interview question.)

Comment: Nice.+1 for this.

Comment: But it is worth mentioning that by replacing `System.out`, you have to take care to do things like ensuring your tests don't run in parallel, because that might cause a test to fail due to interference between cases. Also: "I think it's a terrible interview question" ^^ that.